# VB.NET program crashing on other pc's

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a launcher for a game I am making. The program works perfectly fine on my other computer. I recently transferred the source to my computer. I'm having issues though, I tried debugging the application and I got this error.

I figured out the issue. This code right here

```
.GetVersionInfo("C:\Users\eriger777\Desktop\test\bin\Launcher.exe")
```

Was trying to execute a file that wasn't there :3.

```
An error occurred creating the form.
```

Here's the code that's causing the error.

```
          <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
    Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
        Me.MainForm = Global.Launcher.frmMain
    End Sub
End Class
```

Stack Trace

```
 at Launcher.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
   at Launcher.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_frmMain()
   at Launcher.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() in C:\Users\Gryphon\Downloads\Launcher\Launcher Source Main\Launcher Source\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at Launcher.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Have you instantiated the frmMain class? hmm bu t that doesn't explain how it works on your other PC... I'd start the investigation at this line here: `C:\Users\Gryphon\Downloads\Launcher\Launcher Source Main\Launcher Source\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35`

Comment: Yes I believe so. Like I said it works on my other computer. But it wont work on the new one.

Comment: Are you using any ActiveX controls or a Dll that may not be registered on the new computer?

Comment: do you want to answer this quesiton yourself so that people know its solved and dont spend time troubleshooting it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. This code right here

> .GetVersionInfo("C:\Users\eriger777\Desktop\test\bin\Launcher.exe")
>   Was trying to execute a file that wasn't there :3.